# UISearchDisplayController Text Did Change Lagging Behind

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I am trying to search through a list of users in my Parse database. To do so I have a search bar controller and table view. When a user is searching, it seems like the search results are a letter behind. For example if I search "Be" it will show all the names starting with "B" instead of "Be" and when I search "Ben" it shows all the users starting with "Be".

Here is my textDidChange Method:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

NSString *string = searchText;
string = string.lowercaseString;
if(string.length>0){
        PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
        [query whereKey:@"name_lower" containsString:string];
        [query whereKey:@"username" notEqualTo:currentUser.username];
        [query orderByAscending:@"name_lower"];
        [query setLimit:1000];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array,NSError *error){
            if(!error){
                results = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:array];

                [_mainTableView reloadData];

            }else{
                [ProgressHUD showError:@"Error Searching"];
            }
        }];
}else{
    NSLog(@"NO RESULTS");
    results = nil;
    [_mainTableView reloadData];
}

}
```

Then in my cellforrow:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


    PFUser *user = results[indexPath.row];
    [user fetchIfNeeded];



    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - @%@",user[@"name"],user[@"username"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user[@"university"];
}
```

Comment: Ben. You should update all UI related components on the main thread. This is a common issue with new comers to Parse.

Comment: And FYI, if iOS 7 isn't a priority deployment target, I would suggest foregoing UISearchDisplayController and transition to UISearchController since UISearchDisplayController is deprecated starting iOS 8. It will make it easier on you to do it now as opposed to later

Comment: @soulshined thanks for the suggestion, I actually am still supporting iOS 7 but I will keep that in mind for when i stop supporting it.

Comment: No problem I understand, that's why I said _if_. Do you understand what putting the UI components on the main thread means?

Comment: @soulshined I don't think so, could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey try to put constraints like this:

`[query whereKey:@"name_lower" hasPrefix:string];`

instead of

`[query whereKey:@"name_lower" containsString:string];`

After all I would do it this way:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

      NSString *string = searchText;
      string = string.lowercaseString;
      if(string.length>0){
          PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
          [query whereKey:@"name_lower" hasPrefix:string];
          [query whereKey:@"username" notEqualTo:[[PFUser currentUser] username]];
          [query orderByAscending:@"name_lower"];
          [query setLimit:1000];
          [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array,NSError *error){
               if(!error){
                    results = array;

                    [_mainTableView reloadData];

               } else {
                    [ProgressHUD showError:@"Error Searching"];
               }
           }];
      } else {
          NSLog(@"NO RESULTS");
          results = nil;
          [_mainTableView reloadData];
      }
}
```

Comment: this actually seemed to really help the issue, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: In one of my projects I used custom made search field with UITextField and it worked like a charm, unless there is different mechanics behind the UISearchBar delegate everything should work